# Embed Iframe of one subdomain inside another

Tags: html, nginx, iframe, dns

Heyo, I'm trying to iframe embed content from one subdomain inside another, eg. embed `mail-app.site.co` inside `admin.site.co`. The admin uses iframe properties `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts"`. Is there a way to make this work? I found that `document.domain` used to be a way (now deprecated), but in my case both sites are in a subdomain, so I'm not sure how that'd work. I also found something mentioning `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.site.co`, but I'm not sure how this works with the allow-same-origin sandbox property. Anyone got any clues ? :)